# Using Robolectric's ShadowNfcAdapter to unit test a NFC helper class

Tags: android, unit-testing, nfc, robolectric

I'm trying to use Robolectric to test a NFC helper class. Simplified, I'm doing something like this:

```
Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class)
    .create()
    .start()
    .resume()
    .get();
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = ShadowNfcAdapter.getNfcAdapter(activity);
```

and then exercise my NFC helper class as it does something like this:

```
if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
  //more stuff
}
```

However, calling `nfcAdapter.isEnabled()` causes a null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.isEnabled(NfcAdapter.java:621)
at <package>.test_NfcIntent_shouldPostToBus(NfcHelperTest.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The exception looks to be coming from Android's `NfcAdapter.java`

```
public boolean isEnabled() {
    try {
        return sService.getState() == STATE_ON;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        attemptDeadServiceRecovery(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

where `sService` is null. Indeed, when I use the debugger I can see that `nfcAdapter`'s fields are all either null or objects which themselves have null fields.

Is this the correct way to be using `ShadowNfcAdapter`?  Alternatively, what would be the correct way to test that a NFC helper class is doing the correct things when it is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with Robolectric and I don't only one possible way to fix it now will be to write own Shadow class.

I've created issue on the Robolectric github https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2059

Comment: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/2088 solves #2059. Therefore, use robolectric 3.0 or above and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Coud you try like this:

```
final Activity activty = Robolectric.setupActivity(Activity.class);
NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activty);

final ShadowNfcAdapter shadowNfcAdapter = shadowOf(adapter);

shadowNfcAdapter.isEnabled()
```

Comment: `ShadowNfcAdapter` doesn't have `isEnabled()` http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowNfcAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

worked with robolectric 3.2.2

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager)  
context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
Shadows.shadowOf(nfcAdapter).setEnabled(true);
```